# Varbinary data INTO text and vice versa

Tags: mysql, text, special-characters, varbinary

I got some `varbinary(24)` data in my mysql row, and I want to convert it into normal text and vice versa , the important thing is that `varbinary` contains special (Polish `ąśżćęł`) characters, and they can not be lost during convering the data.

How it can be done?

Varbinary example field example:

```
bfebb1e2c0c720b8c1c5e420202020202020202020202020
```

Comment: This seems to be the case, too, with recent MediaWiki (or my misconfigured instance), which uses `utf8` as the character set, and `VARBINARY` for columns like `page.page_title`. The accepted solution can be used as part of a `SELECT` query to get page titles back in human-readable form, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this can be done using [CONVERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) when you know the original chartset:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->   CONVERT(x'ece0ece020ecfbebe020f0e0ecf320202020202020202020'
    ->           USING cp1251) as s;
+--------------------------------------+
| s                                    |
+--------------------------------------+
| мама мыла раму                       |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

But I failed to find a chartset to decode `bfebb1e2c0c720b8c1c5e420202020202020202020202020` to anything human readable.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your reply. When I'm using your query to convert my Hex: `50656c6572796e61204dea7374776120` I don't get the correct result. As the correct result from `50656c6572796e61204dea7374776120` should be `Peleryna Męstwa` (remember to keep Polish characters [ąęśćżę])!

Comment: @Cyclone, as I have told, I can not figure out in which charset you are pushing data in that field. It is you who should know this. And if the charset is known and supported by mysql you can substitute `cp1251` with the charset and that will be the answer.

Comment: Well, there isn't specified any charset, all I know that table option has `latin1_swedish_ci` charset. Could you give me a query example, how can I turn text like `Peleryna Męstwa` (with Polish characters) into hex and vice versa?

Comment: @cyclone, `latin1_swedish_ci` is the collation of the field not the charset. It seems the connection from your application to the database is misconfigured, that is the connection encoding is defaulted to `latin1`, but the application send data to the database in some other encoding (encoded with other charset). As result, only your application outputs the data correctly.

Comment: @cyclone, Unfortinatelly, to fix it, you will have to pull all the data from the database through your application, then adjust the connection settings (add charset=utf8 and be sure that all data is encoded into utf-8 when passed to MySQL), alter the tables by changing the charset of the text fields to `utf8`, and load the data back into the database.